# Group by on all columns efficient way for multiple col

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on SQL query.. my Table1 has 50 columns and Table2 has 20 col.. I'm doing left join from table1 to Table2 and I would like to apply group by on all columns ... One way is mentioning all columns else is there any efficient way to handle this .. please advise

Comment: Why _apply group by on all columns_?

Comment: Sorry, but the question makes no sense.

Comment: @jarlh , it is the logic of our expected output .. so if we do group by it will be solved

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing much more about the data it is more difficult to help you, but you could try something like this

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id);
```

Comment: Appreciate your help @EJ Egyed